# How can i insert something just before the close tag of an element?

Tags: php, domdocument

I need to correct something in a lot of html documents.

So, i have a structure like this in my body (simplified) :

```
<body>
    <div id="inter">
        <!-- some content -->
    </div>
</body>
```

I need to insert something just before the close tag of my `div id="inter"`. I have to make use of PHP and DOMDocument I guess.

So I get something like:

```
<body>
    <div id="inter">
        <!-- some content -->
        @insert something here
    </div>
</body>
```

In my `<div id="inter">`, I can have a lot of content, like other `div`, `image`, `span`, etc.

Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want PHP Code inside of `<div></div>` tags?

Comment: You want to insert it after some event? Or?

Comment: No, just a comment like <!-- Hello -->

Comment: @HarmeetKaur eeeeeeew innerhtml... Don't use that.

Comment: Do you want that stuff to be included dynamically or by using PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`createElement()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) and [`appendChild()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php):

```
$newElem = $doc->createElement('p', 'New element');
$doc->getElementById('inter')->appendChild($newElem);
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/GMGjkd

If you want to add a comment you can simply use the following:

```
$newComment = $doc->createComment('New comment');
$doc->getElementById('inter')->appendChild($newComment);
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/QMuDMt

Comment: Yes, but if i want insert a comment like <!-- blabla --> ?

Answer (score 0):

[`appendChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) will add a node to the end of another node.

You can create a comment node with [`DOMComment`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domcomment.php)